# Rewrite Rule for fonts in css

Tags: css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, fonts, url-rewriting

I got a some CSS files I don't want to touch. In those CSS files, several fonts get setted

CSS

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'my font';
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url("/fonts/myfont.eot");
  src: url("/fonts/myfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/fonts/myfont.ttf") format("truetype");
}
```

They all get loaded from the "/fonts/..." location.
But they should get loaded from "/public/fonts/...".

Is there any chance to use .htaccess for an rewrite rule ?
Someone got an example ?

Thanks for helping out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably change the actual URLs in your content, as it would be a bit faster than using mod_rewrite. But a rule like this should suffice:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/public/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^(fonts/.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

if you put that in the appropriate place in the htaccess file in your document root.